# NavigationView behavior differences in iOS 13.3 vs. 13.5

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The Code I'm using below is a fresh and simple app with a minimum target of 13.0.  I have created two identical simulators an iPhone 11 Pro Max running 13.3 and another running 13.5.

Executing the code below produces very different results on the two platforms however....

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                Text("Hello world")
                .navigationBarTitle("First View")
            }.tabItem {
                Text("Home")
            }
        }
            
    }
    
    init() {
        let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().previewDevice(.init(rawValue: "iPhone XS Max"))
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm not sure why this is the case in behavior differences between the platform and I'm curious if there was ever a radar opened about it or if this is just a known bug in 13.3.  If it is a known bug, is there a workaround besides embedding a UINavigationController into SwiftUI?

Comment: I have come across quite a few SwiftUI differences when testing on iOS 13.0-13.3 vs 13.4-13.5. It seems Apple made a couple undocumented changes. One particular example is `minimumScaleFactor` not working on <iOS13.3 (it applies scaling even when the set font size fits the label), while the same code works perfectly on 13.4/5.

Comment: @DávidPásztor yeah it seems that way which is very unfortunate and quite an unstable way to roll out changes.  I believe one solution is for me to set my minimum target to 13.5 since that seems to be the most stable option that behaves consistently with the documentation.  I'm curious how you solved some of those issues yourself though?  Did you set your min target to 13.5 or did you wrap old UIKit items into SwiftUI?

Comment: Sadly updating minimum target was not an option for me. So far I always found a workaround that works on all iOS 13 versions without having to resort to UIKit types, but quite often it was a pain, since these are undocumented changes/bugs, so the only solution was trial and error.

Comment: Yikes!  Well thanks for the heads up.  That is very unfortunate that you have to reach into  SwifUI items and "fix" things that shouldn't be an issue in the first place.  But... that's the price of using the latest and greatest things I guess.  Thanks for you input though I appreciate it!